# Posición de la palabra nunca en una frase

Tags: orden-de-palabras

Ayer estaba viendo el informativo y dijeron esta frase:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que nunca ha tenido Francia.

Quizá es que yo no lo uso de esa manera, pero la palabra `nunca` en esa frase no me suena bien. Yo hubiera utilizado frases como:

> Nunca ha habido un presidente mas impopular en Francia que Hollande.
>
> Francia nunca ha tenido un presidente más impopular que Hollande.

O simplemente quitando la palabra `nunca`, aunque el significado es menos dramático que el del ejemplo:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que ha tenido Francia.

Pero claro, que a mi no me suene bien no significa que sea gramaticalmente incorrecta. Mi pregunta es, ¿se puede utilizar la palabra `nunca` como en el ejemplo de la primera frase?

Comment: Ciertamente suena extraño, aunque a mi entender "nunca" sirve para enfatizar la frase y debe ser correcto.

Comment: En mi opinión la primera frase sería correcta. _"Nunca"_ es un complemento circunstancial de tiempo y puede ser colocado donde está. Cómo _te suene_ es otra cosa distinta. Prueba a sustituir por _"jamás"_ o _"en su historia"_ o cambiarlo de posición  _"...que ha tenido NUNCA Francia"_ o _"...que ha tenido Francia NUNCA". Todas son válidas y equivalentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con esta sentencia:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que nunca **ha** tenido Francia.

no es el adverbio *"nunca"*, sino el uso del presente perfecto del indicativo, cuando el subjuntivo es más adecuado:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que Francia nunca **haya** tenido.

El uso de subjuntivo es necesario en esta frase, porque *"que Francia nunca haya tenido un presidente más impopular"* es un hecho hipotético.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. El hablante afirma; por tanto, no se necesita el subjuntivo para nada (probablemente se refiere a que el índice de popularidad que ha obtenido Hollande en alguna encuesta es el más bajo de toda la historia). Y el tiempo verbal es correcto, porque se refiere a toda las historia de Francia hasta este mismo momento.

Comment: @Gorpik El hablante afirma, lo que explica el uso del indicativo del verbo ser ("es"). Yo creo que esta frase es, gramaticalmente hablando, similar a *"ella ahorra dinero para cuando lo necesite"*.

Comment: Dices que el hecho de que Francia nunca haya tenido un presidente más impopular es un hecho hipotético; yo digo que no, que al menos para el hablante no lo es. El subjuntivo se podría usar si el primer verbo estuviera en futuro (*Hollande se convertirá en el presidente más impopular que nunca haya tenido Francia*), porque ese *haya* se refiere también a un instante del futuro y, por tanto, hipotético. Pero en este caso no.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque ahora estoy convencido de que mi anterior respuesta no es correcta, no puedo borrarla porque ya ha sido aceptada. Gorpik me ha hecho ver en los comentarios que el problema con la sentencia:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que nunca **ha tenido** Francia.

no es debido al uso del pretérito perfecto *"ha tenido"*. Gorpik argumenta que el hablante está declarando un hecho, que Francia nunca ha tenido un presidente más impopular, y que por tanto el uso del pretérito perfecto está justificado.

En esta nueva respuesta voy a proponer una tesis alternativa. El problema de esta sentencia no se explica solamente con la posición del complemento adverbial *"nunca"*, sino también por la posición del sujeto *Francia*.

El español, como mucho otros idiomas, tiene preferencia por el orden *sujeto-verbo-predicado*. Es posible re-escribir la sentencia original de manera que siga este orden y suene más natural:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que **Francia ha tenido nunca**.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que en este caso es una mala traducción de una noticia del inglés al español.
Puede ser que la frase original en inglés haya usado **ever** cuya traducción directa al español es **nunca** y el traductor no haya reparado en el contexto de la frase al utilizarla.

Answer (score 1):

A mi también me suena rara la primera frase, pues *nunca* no es necesario. La siguiente expresa lo mismo:

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que Francia ha tenido.

u

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular de Francia de todos los tiempos.

O bien:

> Nunca antes había tenido Francia un presidente tan impopular.

si realmente requieres usar *nunca*.

Answer (score 1):

Es simplemente una elección de estilo para hacer énfasis en el **nunca**. En este caso,

> Hollande es el presidente más impopular que **nunca** ha tenido Francia.

la posición del **nunca** le da un énfasis especial a la oración, similar a si se la hubiera escrito de esta forma:

> **NUNCA** hubo un presidente más impopular que Hollande

dando una inflexión especial, acentuada, en la intención, convirtiendo a **"nunca"** en el eje central de la oración.